# Cannot read clients from nas table in freeradius only with clients.conf

Tags: linux, centos, freeradius

I have installed freeradius on Centos.

The MySQL database is populated with some data for testing, and the freeradiusd.conf and sql.conf are configured.

The RADIUS server is able to connect with the MySQL database, and I can authenticate users from it. I also have a remote RADIUS client configured that is working with my captive portal and RADIUS server, however, it only works when I have the client's IP address configured in `/etc/raddb/clients.conf`. It does not work using the MySQL 'nas' table.

In other words, freeradius does not seem to be querying my nas table from the MySQL database.

In my `/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/sql` file I have following:

```
# Table to keep radius client info
nas_table = "nas"

# Set to 'yes' to read radius clients from the database ('nas' table)
read_clients = yes
```

In my nas table I have following:

```
id       nasname       shortname       type       ports       secret  server      community       description
1       xx.xx.xx.xx       NULL       other       NULL       testing123 
default      NULL       RADIUS Client
```

... where xx.xx.xx.xx is the correct IP address of my RADIUS client.

When I try to log in via the captive portal, with freeradius running in debug mode, I get the following:

```
Wed Aug  8 06:39:11 2018 : Info: Ready to process requests
Wed Aug  8 06:39:19 2018 : Error: Ignoring request to auth address * port 1812 bound to server default from unknown client xx.xx.xx.xx port 55546 proto udp
Wed Aug  8 06:39:19 2018 : Info: Ready to process requests
Wed Aug  8 06:39:21 2018 : Error: Ignoring request to auth address * port 1812 bound to server default from unknown client xx.xx.xx.xx port 55546 proto udp
Wed Aug  8 06:39:21 2018 : Info: Ready to process requests
Wed Aug  8 06:39:24 2018 : Error: Ignoring request to auth address * port 1812 bound to server default from unknown client xx.xx.xx.xx port 55546 proto udp
Wed Aug  8 06:39:24 2018 : Info: Ready to process requests
eWed Aug  8 06:39:28 2018 : Error: Ignoring request to auth address * port 1812 bound to server default from unknown client xx.xx.xx.xx port 55546 proto udp
```

I noticed in the debug output that the data in nas are being loaded

```
Wed Aug  8 09:07:58 2018 : Debug: rlm_sql (sql): Reserved connection (0)
Wed Aug  8 09:07:58 2018 : Debug: rlm_sql (sql): Executing select query: SELECT id, nasname, shortname, type, secret, server FROM nas
Wed Aug  8 09:07:58 2018 : Debug: rlm_sql (sql): Adding client xx.xx.xx.xx (xx.xx.xx.xx) to default clients list
Wed Aug  8 09:07:58 2018 : Debug: Adding client xx.xx.xx.xx/32 (xx.xx.xx.xx) to prefix tree 32
Wed Aug  8 09:07:58 2018 : Debug: rlm_sql (xx.xx.xx.xx): Client "xx.xx.xx.xx" (sql) added
Wed Aug  8 09:07:58 2018 : Debug: rlm_sql (sql): Released connection (0)
Wed Aug  8 09:07:58 2018 : Debug:   # Instantiating module "pap" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/pap
Wed Aug  8 09:07:58 2018 : Debug:   # Instantiating module "reject" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
Wed Aug  8 09:07:58 2018 : Debug:   # Instantiating module "fail" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
Wed Aug  8 09:07:58 2018 : Debug:   # Instantiating module "ok" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
Wed Aug  8 09:07:58 2018 : Debug:   # Instantiating module "handled" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
Wed Aug  8 09:07:58 2018 : Debug:   # Instantiating module "invalid" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
Wed Aug  8 09:07:58 2018 : Debug:   # Instantiating module "userlock" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
Wed Aug  8 09:07:58 2018 : Debug:   # Instantiating module "notfound" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
Wed Aug  8 09:07:58 2018 : Debug:   # Instantiating module "noop" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
Wed Aug  8 09:07:58 2018 : Debug:   # Instantiating module "updated" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/always
Wed Aug  8 09:07:58 2018 : Debug:   # Instantiating module "monthlycounter" from file /etc/raddb/mods-enabled/sqlcounter
```

Any help would be greatly apprciated!
PS: I tried changing the shortname in the nas table the same as the ip but it still didn't work

Comment: This seems to affect my freeradius => mysql implementation as well. Does this happen on version 3 of freeradius.